# Refer to the latest Version ID of a S3 object in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I want to refer to the latest Version id of a s3 obejct in my CloudFormation template, how should I refer it?

I have the below variables as my parameters in the CloudFormation template

- the stored S3 bucket: `LambdaS3`
- the stored S3 object name(a zip file): `Lambdafilename`

The below code is my existing intrinsic function reference, how should I fix it?

```yaml
        Version: !GetAtt
          - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3::::${LambdaS3}/${IoTProvisioningLambdafilename}.zip.Versions[?IsLatest].[VersionId]"
```

Comment: My goal is to update the CloudFormation stack by using the latest S3 object verisonId which can be done through AWS CLi. So I solved it by using AWS CLi rather than CloudFormation template.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't use** `Sub` with `GetAtt`. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html#getatt-supported-functions):

> For the Fn::GetAtt logical resource name, you can't use functions. You must specify a string that's a resource's logical ID.

You must **hardcode** the full name of your S3 object. The only way around that is to use [macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

Comment: Could you please provide the code to achieve my goal by using CloudFormation macros?

Comment: @KenLEE Sorry, SO does not work like that. You write the code. if it does not work, you make new question with your code and any errors you have.

Comment: Do you mean I can achieve it by using macros?

Comment: @KenLEE Yes, you can write the marco. A [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) could also be used. I can add it to the answer.

Comment: Yes, please do!